# global variable and reduce database accesses in PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new to PHP+MySQL and followed an example to build a web page.

Basically, my front page reads the databas, retrieves all the items, and lists on the page. Each item has a link to a new page showing its details.

the list page:

```
//itemlist.html.php
<html><body>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
    <li><a href="?C1=<?php echo($item['c1']); ?>">
    <?php echo($item['c1']); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</body></html>
```

the item page:

```
//itemeach.html.php
<html><body>
<h1><?php echo($c1) ?></h1>
<p><?php echo($c2) ?></p>
</body></html>
```

the index page:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['C1']))
{
    /*
    I want to reuse $iteminfos and get value for $c1 and $c2
    */
    include 'itemeach.html.php';
    exit();
}
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM TB');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $items[] = array('c1' => $row['c1'], 'c2' => $row['c2']);
}
include 'itemlist.html.php';
?>
```

I removed the unnecessary code. Since when the first time it loads index.php, $infos is retrieved. I want to avoid accessing to database again to get one specific item, so I am thinking about re-use $infos. But it becomes null when I trigger 'C1'. Is this possible to keep $items as a global variable? or is there other way to do that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could store the retrieved rowset in the $_SESSION superglobal. Like: $_SESSION['items'] = $items; and put that after the while loop.

Comment: doing a new db request for each page is the standard approach.

Comment: Instead of open a new window, I am now considering pop a div (+css). I know how to use javascript to do a static pop div, but how to use php+javascript, i.e., context in the pop div is dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the retrieved rowset in the $_SESSION superglobal. Like:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['items']) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM TB');
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rowData[] = array('c1' => $row['c1'], 'c2' => $row['c2']);
    }

    $_SESSION['items'] = $rowData;
}

$items = $_SESSION['items'];
```

But yeah what Dagon said is true.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the query and while loop to above the if (isset($_GET['C1'])) line, this will make $items available to the itemeach.html.php script. If you could post the contents of itemeach.html.php we can help you further.